# Can a signed assembly be used only by a signed assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Can a signed assembly be used by a signed assemblies ? I want to know if I signed an assembly as strongly named will it not possible to be used by a non-signed assembly ?  Please guide how to sign a assembly as strongly named ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Q: Can a strongly name assembly be used by a strongly name assembly?

A: Yes, of course

> Q: I want to know if I signed an asambly as strongly named will it not
>   possible to be used by a simple assambly?

A: I think you're asking if a "normal" (unsigned) assembly can call a strongly named assembly?  Again - yes, of course

... HOWEVER ...

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad.aspx
>
> When you reference a strong-named assembly, you expect to get certain
>   benefits, such as versioning and naming protection. If the
>   strong-named assembly then references an assembly with a simple name,
>   which does not have these benefits, you lose the benefits you would
>   derive from using a strong-named assembly and revert to DLL conflicts.
>   Therefore, strong-named assemblies can only reference other
>   strong-named assemblies.

In other words, ANY assembly can use a strongly signed assembly.  But a strongly signed assembly can only use OTHER strongly signed assemblies.

Comment: Thanks paulsm4, do u mean strongly name save from dll hell ? Is it strngly nameing that allow two assamblies of same name in a folder and assamblies with no strongly name cannot be in a folder ? plz guide

Answer (score 10):

No, it's the other way round - you can't use an unsigned assembly from a signed assembly, but the reverse is fine.

After all, bear in mind that all the system assemblies (mscorlib, System.dll etc) are strongly-named... and you can obviously use those from non-strongly-named assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

No. Strong named (signed) assemblies can be used by all libraries, but they cannot use non-signed assemblies.

Same goes for applications. Signed applications must only use signed assemblies.